# how to revise xml parser exception "<?xml ... ?> prolog must be at the document start"

Tags: java, xml, jdom

i use follows code to get a XML Document (by JDOM in java):

```
SAXBuilder builder = new SAXBuilder();
Document doc= builder.build(new URL("http://www.sasatuan.com/api/api.php"));
```

and i get a Exception:

```
org.jdom.input.JDOMParseException: Error in building:
 http://www.sasatuan.com/api/api.php:1: <?xml ... ?> occurs after content.  The
<?xml ... ?> prolog must be at the document start.: http://www.sasatuan.com/api/
api.php:1: <?xml ... ?> occurs after content.  The <?xml ... ?> prolog must be a
t the document start.
        at org.jdom.input.SAXBuilder.build(SAXBuilder.java:473)
        ...
```

i type this URL `http://www.sasatuan.com/api/api.php` in IE,it's be ok,but in firefox or chrome,it's same error.

this xml header not at the document start,so jdom can't read it.

i think trim() the xml content before build can revise this problem, i want know how to do this.

thanks for help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have other XML files which are similarly broken that you need to read? If not, I would personally try to get in touch with the owner of the website. That XML is simply invalid - and it would probably be an easy job to fix it, which would help *everyone* rather than just you.

If that doesn't appeal, it would probably be easiest to download the content as a string, trim it in memory, and then load it. You *could* mess around trying to skip the relevant bits of the input stream, but that's more likely to be fiddly.